# PHPUnit accept application/json

Tags: phpunit, webtest

I have test written in PHPUnit and I want to send information to server that I want get json response.

I was trying to send `'accept' => 'application/json'` header with `client->request` method as third of fifth parameter, but it doesn't work.

My code:

```
class PostControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    protected $client;

    public function setUp()
    {
        self::bootKernel();
        $this->client = static::createClient();
    }

    protected function testOK()
    {
        $this->client->request('GET', '/posts', [
            'accept => 'application/json',
        ], [], [
            'accept => 'application/json',
        ]);
    }
}
```

But if I do the same with RESTplugin for google chrome and also send these header everything is OK.

I don't know what can be wrong, because in theory it should works.

Comment: What is exactly going wrong? Do you get an error in your client request or do you get something like `application/xml` as result instead?

Comment: Server returns normal html site. Like without any special headers.

Comment: What's the answer here?

Answer (score 0):

REST services looks at `Content-Type` instead of `accepts`. Adding 
 `'Content-Type' => 'application/json'` to your request header should fix the problem.

Comment: Still the same problem. And if I use `accept` with RestClient chrome extension server returns json. So `accept` should be OK.